# Adding bower module ng-js-Tree to an AngularJs project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstree

I followed this steps to use ng-js-tree in my AngularJS project:

1)I installed the dependencies through `npm install ng-js-tree --save`

2)On my Index.html, y added the following line: 
`<script src="bower_components/ng-js-tree/dist/ngJsTree.js"></script>`

3)I Loaded the dependencies in the following way:

```
.state('dashboard.form', {
            templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
            url: '/form',
            controller: 'ChartCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return  $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'ngJsTree',
                            files: ['bower_components/ng-js-tree/ngJsTree.js']
                        }),
                        $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'sbAdminApp',
                            files: ['scripts/controllers/form.js']
                        })
                }
            }
        })`
```

4) I defined the controller with its appropriate function: (not going to post the entire function, I'm pretty sure it's not necessary)

`myModule.controller('treeCtrl', treeCtrl);`

5)And finally, I posted it on the .html file:

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="treeCtrl as vm">
      <div js-tree="vm.treeConfig" should-apply="vm.applyModelChanges()"
                     ng-model="vm.treeData" tree="vm.treeInstance"
                      tree-events="ready:vm.readyCB;create_node:vm.createCB"></div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't show anything, and it throws the following error:

`TypeError: scope.tree.jstree is not a function`

I found [this help](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree/issues/13) on github, but I'm doing what it is saying and can't make it work... any help?

EDITED with tree file...both .js are the same (tested)
[image]

Comment: are you sure the dependency is loaded?  files: ['../bower_components/ng-js-tree/ngJsTree.js'] ??

Comment: @ManuAntony yep, it's in the code and I've loaded other modules the same way and they work, but I don't know if I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your 'index.html':

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.css" />
```